# What is best the Open Source Java Encryption Lib?

Tags: java, encryption

What is the Open Source Java Encryption Lib?I wanna encrypt some text with this Lib?

Comment: The best answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/).

Comment: What do you thing about jasypt?

Comment: I have never used it, can't comment. Bouncy Castle works well for me.

Comment: jasypt is a higher level set of APIs built on top of JCE. You probably want to look at what it offers too since it will make basic crypto tasks easier, regardless of which JCE implementation you use.